# How do I encrypt an encryption key?

Tags: ruby, security, encryption, openssl, passwords

I have a password manager that I'm implementing in Ruby. Encrypting the passwords is pretty easy thanks to OpenSSL, but I also need to ask the user for a master password, which is a password to view, change, and add passwords. Once the user enters their master password in, I intend for it to be encrypted and stored in the passwords file somehow. But OpenSSL encrypting and decrypting requires a password. For normal passwords, the key is the master password, so what should I make the encryption key for the master password?

Comment: Why not *use* the user supplied master password *as* the master password to decrypt the user’s keys (to view/manipulate)? Or: what am I missing?

Comment: In a “real” keyword management application, I’d want at least one additional layer for pepper and rotations and service isolation. Although that still leaves the question in the first comment open.

Comment: You should not encrypt the master password at all, you should instead use a password hash to both verify the master password and generate the data encryption key from it. Argon2 is recommended, not sure what is supported in Ruby.

Comment: Hints: I would use a PBKDF such as Argon2 to derive multiple keys / derived secrets. One can be used as "key check value" to test if the master password is correct, so that you don't confuse checking correctness with decryption of the database (although you might get the wrong error if somebody messed with it). Do store a version number and possibly work factor / iteration count and of course a 64 -128 bit salt as well.